# Creating A Bar chart in R using a subset of years

Tags: r, bar-chart

I currently have a dataset that has columns for "Winner's Nationality" and also a column for Years. I created a barplot to show the data using the following code:

```
counts <- table(tdf$Winner.s.Nationality)
barplot(counts[order(counts, decreasing = TRUE)])
```

And then plotted counts. However, I now want to plot the same data but with the Year coming after 1950. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column with the years is named `Year` and at the same level in your dataset (tdf$Winner.s.Year), have you tried something like:

```
counts <- table(tdf$Winner.s.Nationality[tdf$Winner.s.Year > 1950, ]) # or '1950' if text format
barplot(counts[order(counts, decreasing = TRUE)])
```

something along those lines should get you close to the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help, when I run this I get an error that says Error in `[.default`(tdf$Winner.s.Nationality, tdf$Year > 1950, ) : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 0):

```
# library(tidyverse)    # Uncomment this command if tidyverse not loaded
x <- tribble( # tribble() makes for easy quick dataframe defn. at console
  ~Winner.s.Nationality, ~year,
  "A",1948,
  "B",1949,
  "A",1950,
  "B",1951) %>%
filter(year >= 1950)
counts <- table(x$Winner.s.Nationality)
barplot(counts)
```

Comment: For those (like me) that do not have the mega meta package installed, `library(dplyr)` is sufficient.